# Showing self adjointness

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, spectral-theory

$\pi:$ $Lx=\sum_{j=0}^{n}(p_{n-j}x^{(j)})^{(j)}$,$\,\,$ $x^{(j)}(a)=x^{(j)}(b)=0,\, j=0,1,...,n-1.$

where $p_{n-j}\in C^{n-j}[a,b]$ are real and $p_0(t)\neq0$ on $[a,b]$.

I want to show that the problem $\pi$ is self-adjoint. My approach as in the following:

$<Lx,y>=<\sum_{j=0}^{n}(p_{n-j}x^{(j)})^{(j)},y>=\sum_{j=0}^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{j}\dbinom{j}{k} <p_{n-j}^{(k)}x^{(2j-k)},y>$

Since $x^{(j)}(a)=x^{(j)}(b)=0,\, j=0,1,...,n-1$, I obtain the following formula by applying partial integration recursively,

$<Lx,y>=\sum_{j=0}^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{j}\dbinom{j}{k} <x,((-1)^kp_{n-j}^{(k)}y)^{(2j-k)}>$. Therefore I have

$L^*y=\sum_{j=0}^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{j}\dbinom{j}{k} ((-1)^kp_{n-j}^{(k)}y)^{(2j-k)}$.

Now at this point i need to show that $L=L^*$. But i couldn't can you give me any suggestion to show this result and can you correct my calculation above if it is incorrect.

Thanks in advance!...

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't open parantheses for Leibnitz rule, use the boundary conditions with integration by parts instead. Take $y$ that satisfies the same boundary data:
$$y^{(j)}(a)=y^{(j)}(b)=0,\, j=0,1,\dots,n-1,$$then
$$\int_a^b (px^{(j)})^{(j)}y\ dt =(px^{(j)})^{(j-1)}y\big|_{t=a}^{t=b} - \int_a^b (px^{(j)})^{(j-1)}y^{(1)}\ dt $$
$$=\dots= (-1)^j\int_a^b  px^{(j)}  y^{(j)}\ dt $$
$$=\dots =\int_a^b (py^{(j)})^{(j)}x\ dt $$